# Why would a Virus want hidden files to be shown?

Tags: windows, virus

[What else besides a virus would keep turning on "Show Hidden Files" in WinXP](https://superuser.com/questions/11878/what-else-besides-a-virus-would-keep-turning-on-show-hidden-files-in-winxp) discusses the possibility of a virus setting the show hidden files values to true.

Why would a virus do this?  I would think it would want to make itself a hidden file then always set show hidden files to false.

Answer (score 3):

Well it would show system files, which a user is not used to seeing. They could interpret these new files as part of the virus on the PC and try and delete them, causing more problems.

Although most viruses do this the other way around, they will attempt to hide files that it created on your system to deter their removal.

Answer (score 1):

Sloppy coding.  Trying to hide it's files, but showing hidden files at the same time because that's what the author has on his system and he mindlessly copied the same setting across without thinking that not everyone will have it set.

Just because someone writes a virus, it doesn't mean they're a good coder, or that they know their way around windows internals.